# How do I install jekyll on OS X 10.14+?

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

If you try to follow the standard [Jekyll installation instructions](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/) on OS X 10.14+, it fails because header files like ruby.h are missing. Similar problems happen when installing any Ruby package which contains C/C++ extensions.

Discussions of this on various web fora give you commands to switch your ruby header directory (because Apple changed it in 10.14.0), but starting in 10.14.5, these don't work either, as Apple eliminated those altogether!

How do you make Jekyll work on a current OS X machine?

Comment: generally, don't use the system ruby - use something like `rbenv` and use that environment to develop against and to install gems against

Comment: If you want to avoid installing `jekyll` locally on your Mac, you can give the `jekyll` docker images a try https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker#jekyll-docker

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to treat the default system Ruby installation in 10.14.5+ as being completely broken for many uses, much like the default system Python installation is. Instead, install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to set up a managed Ruby environment that can use any appropriate software version.

- If you haven't already installed [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), do that first by running

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

from a Terminal.

- Next, install rbenv by running `brew install rbenv ruby-build`.
- Before you try to use rbenv for anything, update your shell. If you're using bash, stick the following code snippet into your .bashrc or .bash_profile:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

For other shells, see [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell) for the best approach. Close and reopen your terminal window (or do your shell's equivalent of `source ~/.bashrc`) before continuing.

- Install a healthy version of Ruby by running `rbenv install 2.6.3` (or whatever the current stable version is -- you can always check that at ruby-lang.org).
- Make it the system default by running `rbenv global 2.6.3`
- To verify this is working correctly, run `which ruby`. You should see something like [your home directory]/.rbenv/shims/ruby. You can also run `ruby -v` and confirm that you're seeing the version you just installed.
- And now the standard Jekyll (or any other package) installation instructions should work for you! For Jekyll, for example, you can now run `gem install --user-install bundler jekyll`.